# Git Repository Created Manually Can't Commit

Tags: xcode, git, repository, commit

After creating a Git Repository using the terminal application using the following commands

Focusing the shell on the project directory

`$ cd ~/Desktop/Myproject`

Setting up the Git Repository

`$ git init`

Preparing the files for the "staging area"

`$ git add .`

Making my first commit

`$ git commit -m 'Initial Checkin'`

When I now try to commit in Xcode, I get

> The operation could not be performed because no valid working copies were found.
>
> Please verify that your files are under source control and try again.

But if I modify any of the project files and $ git status in to shell, it will tell me that what ever file I fiddled around with in Xcode has been modified and the I can commit from there. Why not in Xcode??

I had a loot at [Can't commit changes to local git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148544/cant-commit-changes-to-local-git-repository) but the suggestions did not solve the problem.

Comment: what if you try to commit through terminal? does it go through? or do you get the same error?

Comment: I seems to work through terminal, I am not getting any errors there, not sure what could be there problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If restarting XCode doesn't help, since you are saying it works fine through terminal, try adding it again in XCode.

go to Organzier--> Repositories --> Add Repository (bottom left corner)-->Set the correct values and local path to your project

my guess is, since you created the repository outside XCode, for some reason, its not detecting it right, or is not having the right permissions. Re-adding the repository through XCode may help solve this issue for you.

Comment: I tried that, it shows in Repository Organizer, and it even shows the revisions that I have committed through shell, but, committing via Xcode or at list refreshing still gives me the same error.

Comment: I wish it helped fix the issue. I remember having a similar issue with a svn repo, a few xcode versions back. My team members, on the same version of XCode and OSX wouldn't have this issue. So I guess, its similar to that. (last choice, just try deleting derived data from Organizer-->Projects, it may help)

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen once, and the issue was cleared by quitting and re-opening Xcode.